# Is there a Windows program to use instead/beside ALT-TAB (cycling windows)?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office

I have to make a transcription (audio to text dictation) and have to constantly alternate between <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (Play/Pause in Foobar2000) and <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> (switch between Foobar and MSOffice).

I want to be able to **set a new keyboard shortcut** instead/beside <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>) closer to the other key I use. I use the keyboard only for these  <kbd>SPACE</kbd>  and <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> but the space and difference between them distracts me from the task of listening and dictating.

Ideally, I would prefer to use **a single key** to cycle windows, but that is maybe more complicated. (For example to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>).

I want to be able to disable this feature easily as soon as I stop the job of transcription.

Also, I want something that should **not need Aero** (please, don't ask why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just create a new global hotkey in Foobar2000 to play/pause and skip switching applications altogether?

[image]

This would allow you to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (or even simpler: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) *anywhere* in Windows.

To seek back and ahead in Foobar, add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for 1, 5, or 10 secs etc, as you please.

Comment: Excellent! Ctrl+Alt+Space it's in fact ALTGR-SPACE. the idea is so good that i can add other such keys for foobar for seeking. Again, Foobar2000 is superb.

Comment: @cipricus: You can use any hotkey you like. I just picked Ctrl+Alt+Space as an example. (And now I see that you probably know that already ;D)

Comment: [xmplay](http://www.un4seen.com/) can be used in the same way - although the number of secs to jump back/forward is not customizable: but it's 3 sec and that makes it usable. just like for foobar, a good option to use is 'always on top'.